# Running two if statements in same function

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to code a function where the given angle must be less than 90 degrees and greater than 0 degree. If the angle is in radians, it must be less than pi/2 and greater than 0.

This is my function:

```
def is_valid_angle(s:str)-> bool:
    """
    Returns True if and only if s is a valid angle. See the assignment
    description and examples for more information regarding what's valid

    Examples:
    >>> is_valid_angle("85.3d")
    True
    >>> is_valid_angle("85.3.7D")
    False
    >>> is_valid_angle("90d")
    False
    >>> is_valid_angle("0.001r")
    True
    >>> is_valid_angle("1.5R")
    True
    """
    if s[-1]=='r''R':
        if s < (pi/2):
            if s > 0:
                return true
    if s[-1]=='d''D':
            if s < 90:
                if s > 0:
                    return true
```

Also, I want to know if there's a way to shorten the two `if` statements, by using `else`.

Comment: Why do you try to write this code? Is it a school assignment? It would probably be better to use one of the two formats as your base format and then convert from the other to the base, before testing (most likely as a separate function). ALso, you should split reading in the angle, since it is given in a custom format, and checking if it is in a valid range. Finally, when checking for a valid range, you could use the `and` keyword to test both lower and upper limit in the same `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

***Explanation***: `try` and `except` will check if the string *except* the last character is a number or not. This is done using `s[:-1]` which returns the string from first character up to second last character. If it is not, for ex. in `85.3.7D`, `85.3.7` is not a valid number, it will return `False`. If it is, then it will check for the `if` statements to check for radians or degrees and the range of the angle. Depending on the `if` statements, the corresponding value (`True/False`) will be returned.

```
import numpy as np

def is_valid_angle(s):

    try:
        float(s[:-1])
    except ValueError:
        return False

    if (s[-1]=='r' or s[-1]=='R') and (0 < float(s[:-1]) < np.pi/2):
        return True
    elif (s[-1]=='d' or s[-1]=='D') and (0 < float(s[:-1]) < 90):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

---

```
>>> is_valid_angle("85.3d")
True
>>> is_valid_angle("85.3.7D")
False
>>> is_valid_angle("90d")
False
>>> is_valid_angle("0.001r")
True
>>> is_valid_angle("1.5R")
True
```